# Uncaught (in promise):How to await a function which returns a promise inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am working on awaiting a function that returns a promise inside a loop. But, I was not able to resolve it.

the loop is

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    console.log("row " + i);
    getData(i).then(function (data) {            
        console.log("data of row "+ i +" is "+ data);
    });
}
```

The output is:

```
row 0
row 1
row 2
data of row undefined data
data of row undefined data
data of row undefined data
```

i've tried to put the loop in a `Async Context` and await for the `getData` function but it causes `deadlock` with the error of `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` at `row 0` like below:

```
getRows().then(async function (rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log("row " + i);
        await getData(i).then(function (data) {            
            console.log("data of row "+ i +" is "+ data);
        });
    }
});
```

Of worth to say, i'v defined `promise reject function` like this:`reject(undefined)` but i'v tried `reject(false)` and `reject(null)` also. However, No difference and `Uncaught (in promise)` exception throws and `deadlock` happens.

```
function getData(row) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        whenAvailable("read", function (t) {
            read("data", row, 0, 1, true, "so").then(function (data) {
                if (data != undefined) {
                    resolve(data);
                } else {                   
                    reject(false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

and also i'v check other **stackoverflow** related question but they were not suitable for my problem.

Can you help me overcome this problem?

### Update

i did below as **@SunilLama** said

```
getRows().then(async function (rows) {
if (rows != undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log("rows " + i);
        await getData(i).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

again `deadlock` with exception of

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209194/discussion-on-question-by-mr-af-uncaught-in-promisehow-to-await-a-function-wh).

Comment: Doesn't `getData` expect a row or row identifier? You currently pass it the index of the clients `rows` array. Or is that the intention? For example `getData(rows[i])` or `getData(rows[i].id)`. Also note that you can't use `i` in callbacks in combination with the `var` keyword, use `let` instead if you are intending to refer to `i` in callbacks.

Comment: @Mr.AF I see that it's self defined, but I don't know what argument `read` expects.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yea it needs to get data from row like `rows[i].id` but for test i only passed `i`

Answer (score 0):

If your point is that each iteration should wait previous one, then one way is to do it with recursion.

```js
var rows = ["a","b","c"];
function getData(i) {
  var promise=  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(rows[i]);
    },1000);
  });
  return promise;
}
function recur(i) {
    i = i || 0; // For first time, makes it zero
    if (i >= rows.length) { return; } // Stop if it's out of range
    console.log("row " + i);
    getData(i).then(function (data) {            
        console.log("data of row "+ i +" is "+ data);
        recur(i + 1); // Call for next iteration
    });
}
recur(); // Call
```

Comment: how it supposed to awaited in loop?

Comment: You don't have to. At start, it executes `recur` function for index 0 and only after success of `getData` is called `recur` for next (1) index.

Comment: I modified my answer and put snippet in it.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping the loop in an `async` function should do it:

```js
function getData(i) {
  var promise=  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(i+1);
    },1000);
  });
  return promise;
}
var main = async() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log("row " + i);
    await getData(i).then(function(data) {
      console.log("data of row " + i + " is " + data);
    },error=> console.log(error));
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: looks charm please let me test it.